# How to eliminate male on male competition?

Tags: biology, society, culture, behaviour

What behavioral and biological changes would be needed to make males not fight each other over females and for females to fight each other for males and to not make males expandle and extremely important for the species?

Comment: Well duh! that's just like so easy you know, just kill all the males accept one 

Comment: There are many potential solutions to this, but no clear criteria for deciding which would constitute a "best answer". Voting to close as opinion-based. To enable reopening, please give more specifics as to what you're after.

Comment: Male what, humans? That would mean reducing testosterone in men and increasing it in women, but that has [substantial implications for the reproductive process](https://www.yourhormones.info/hormones/testosterone/). There's also the evolutionary competition for mates because females (the egg producers) are the limiting resource (i.e., males,. which can fertilize any number of eggs quickly, compete for females, which produce eggs sparingly). You're basically asking for a name change: call the females male and the males female, problem solved. Is there a way to narrow the question?

Comment: How do I make my question non opinion based what should I add or change about it

Comment: Explain how their biology can work at  hundreds of thousands of times the rate of normal humans in pregnancy, how they get the energy into their bodies for that growth. What you've described is very far from human, we'd need to understand much more how  they work.

Comment: The accelerated birth would probably do it. Think about humans for a moment: A man can potentially create a baby every time he has sex, but a woman only once every 9 months. So evolutionarily, it suits a woman to be choosy about the man she cosies up with, to maximise quality rather than quantity. If you take away that limitation (as you did), now the woman can be the aggressive one, and genetically, has an interest in pumping out as many sprogs as possible to spread her genes far and wide. Also, all this baby-making means she has to eat an awful lot and so has to be aggressive and strong.

Comment: @Pelinore I think you need to kill all. Plenty of men still compete with diseased men. Being better than your father, becoming the greatest x or y (or XY) in the world. Etc.

Comment: Is this a troll answer?

Answer (score 9):

**Plumage**

[image: peacocks]

These are not weapons, for doing battle!  How gauche.  Nay, in this world brilliantly bedecked males dazzle the females (and each other!) with glorious feathers, fur tufts, multicolored appendages and eyes like limpid pools.  And not just that.  We showy spectacular males also croon with sexy voices as well as wail plaintively and do that rock and roll scream where I jump up and kick my legs!  Did I mention I also play guitar?  No; please - you are too kind.  I am still just learning.

And ladies - get close.  I will sing less loudly and I promise not to kick.  If you brush up against my feathers it is ok.  That is what they are for.  Now - do you smell that?  That is the great smell of Brut and it is coming from me.  Oh, you with the red hair, you detect a little cinnamon as well?  That is because I just baked cinnamon rolls!  Would you like one?  I'll split one with you.  Dudes I am ok with you guys having some cinnamon rolls too.  I made plenty so we could share.

Yes the men don't need to fight.  We show off by being awesome in dozens of awesome ways as some men already do.   The ladies are competitive but this does not require the world to change much.

Comment: But Willk that ***is*** male on male competition, a lack of actual violence doesn't make it not.

Comment: @Pelinore - but "not fight", peaceful and friendly.  All the things the OP wanted!

Comment: [Ponders] Yeah I guess, his title doesn't really match his questions contents for me but the contents should take precedence over an inaccurate or misleading title I suppose.

Comment: +1 just for the photo

Answer (score 3):

One possible biological change would be to make male births more rare, as in 1/4 of the population or less.

It would not necessarily produce absolutely peaceful males but it should serve to greatly reduce the need for male-on-male aggression.

If the disparity is significantly greater you could even approach a point where the males cannot be risked because then you don't have a continuing population.

Comment: I think this would actually do the opposite. If 1 male impregnating multiple females is the norm for your species, then there's a winner-takes-all dynamic which would lead to more male competition, not less. See eg Elephant Seals.

Comment: Also it means that every male will average four times as many children as females.   That's a strong pressure to have sons

Comment: As Zas said this will do the opposite this is how you extreme male on male fighting, its a harem species.

Comment: There are multiple outcomes: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21975/how-would-society-function-with-only-one-male-per-generation

Answer (score 2):

I think the obvious solution is for females to reject males who are overly competitive.  Of course, this may provide an inverted competition, males have an incentive, at least to appear, to be very cooperative.

Comment: This makes no sence biologically

Answer (score 2):

One less testosterone. Human males need and produce a large level of testosterone.

testosterone encorages competition. It also increases uperbody mass make men more suited for fighting. You would need to change them so that they need and produced less testosterone. This would make them weaker and less competitive .

Infertile females. Cant have your warrior class coming down with children while in the middle of a campaign. To get the exact results you want then you will also need an expendable class of females to send into battle. Simular to a bee hive. Have your females divied in to groups the hypersexual baby factories and the asexual soldiers/workers.

An intersting possibility would to create a species were females could switch between warrior form and breader form by undergoing a metamorphosis.

Comment: You don't need a metamorphosis at all! Your army is filled of young women, which are more fit to fight, anyway. You don't allow that they meet males in the army (or perhaps provide some long-term contraception when they enroll?), and poor soul that comes back pregnant from leave! They may give birth after finishing their military service, if so they wish. This society wouldn't consider someone younger to be prepared to be a competent mother, anyway.

Comment: We don't know the Tech level they may not have contraception.   We cant assume every society will have the same view on young mothers. In fact at least for humans historically It's usually the opposite, most societies Encouraged women who wanted to become mothers others to become  So as soon as possible. Without knowing what age the females of this species Become Infertile  It's hard to say What would be the norm for most of there societies.  As for not seeing males Similar practices were tried On soldier  Within our own world And they failed to be 100% effective.

Comment: Simply put It's hard to keep soldiers away from the opposite sex. Apart from isolating them alone on a mountain somewhere, Large armies tend to attract camp followers.  many of these camp followers  This will be the opposite sex of your soldiers. Even the ones that are not will bring along their sons and husbands.

Comment: As for the ones coming back pregnant on leave. How exactly are they gonna pause their pregnancy To complete their military service?

Comment: @BryanMcClire: this is worldbuilding. _You can make this society have any view on young mothers that you want._ As for those that come back pregnant, I was trying to imply they would face a harsh punishment. For example they could be expelled without honor and rejected by their family, ending up their days as pariahs. It's up to you if there is a way in this society for them to complete their military service later... or not.

Comment: @Ángel such  That makes techniques have been tried in past with Male soldiers with no success.

Answer (score 0):

### Harsh environment

What females look for is males who survive and provide in difficult circumstances.   Direct competition is counterproductive.   Alliance and even friendship are far more useful.

Comment: harsh environments don't stop male on male fighting if anything they encourage it, few resources means breeding opportunities are also at a premium.